# Authentication token passed to ControllerAdvice is null when running through MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, mockmvc

I am using Spring Boot 1.3, Spring 4.2 and Spring Security 4.0. I am running integration tests using MockMvc, for example:

```
mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .etc;
```

In my tests I am simulating a user login like this:

```
CurrentUser principal = new CurrentUser(user);
Authentication auth =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, "dummypassword",
                    principal.getAuthorities());

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

This works fine for my methods that are annotated with `@PreAuthorize`, for example when calling a method like this from a test:

```
@PreAuthorize("@permissionsService.canDoThisThing(principal)")
public void mySecuredMethod()
```

the principle, my CurrentUser object, is non-null in `PermissionsService#canDoThisThing`.

I have a class annotated with @ControllerAdvice that adds the currently logged-in user to the model so it can be accessed in every view:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CurrentUserControllerAdvice {
    @ModelAttribute("currentUser")
    public CurrentUser getCurrentUser(Authentication authentication) {
        if (authentication == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return (CurrentUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
    }
}
```

This works fine when running the application, however (and this is my problem) - when running my tests the authentication parameter passed in to the getCurrentUser method above is always null. This means any references to the currentUser attribute in my view templates cause errors, so those tests fail.

I know I could get round this by retrieving the principle like this:

```
authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

but I would rather not change my main code just so the tests work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `SecurityContextHolder` does not work when using Spring Security with `MockMvc`. The reason is that Spring Security's `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` attempts to resolve the `SecurityContext` from the `HttpServletRequest`. By default this is done using `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` by retrieving at the `HttpSession` attribute named `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT`. The attribute name is defined by the constant `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY`. Whatever `SecurityContext` is found in the `HttpSession` will then be set on the `SecurityContextHolder` which overrides the value you previously set.

## Manually Solving the Issue

The fix that involves the least amount of change is to set the `SecurityContext` in the `HttpSession`. You can do this using something like this:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/").sessionAttr(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, securityContext))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .etc;
```

The key is to ensure that you set the `HttpSession` attribute named `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` to the `SecurityContext`. In our example, we leverage the constant `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY` to define the attribute name.

## Spring Security Test

Spring Security 4.0 has officially added [test support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test). This is by far the easiest and most flexible way to test your application with Spring Security.

### Add spring-security-test

Since you are using Spring Boot, the easiest way to ensure you have this dependency is to include spring-security-test in your Maven pom. Spring Boot manages the version, so there is no need to specify a version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Naturally, Gradle inclusion would be very similar.

### Setting up MockMvc

In order to [integrate with MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc) there are some steps you must perform outlined in the reference.

The first step is to ensure you use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`. This should come as no surprise since this is a standard step when testing with Spring applications.

The [next step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-setup) is to ensure you build your `MockMvc` instance using `SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()`. For example:

```
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity()) // sets up Spring Security with MockMvc
                .build();
    }

...
```

### Running as a User

Now you can easily run with a specific user. There are two ways of accomplishing this with MockMvc.

#### Using a RequestPostProcessor

The first option is [using a RequestPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-securitycontextholder-rpp). For your example, you could do something like this:

```
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.*;

// use this if CustomUser (principal) implements UserDetails
mvc
    .perform(get("/").with(user(principal)))
    ...

// otherwise use this
mvc
    .perform(get("/").with(authentication(auth)))
    ...
```

#### Using Annotations

You can also use annotations to specify the user. Since you use a custom user object (i.e. CurrentUser), you would probably consider using [@WithUserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withuserdetails) or [@WithSecurityContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withsecuritycontext).

[@WithUserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withuserdetails) makes sense if you expose the `UserDetailsService` as a bean and you are alright with the user being looked up (i.e. it must exist). An example of `@WithUserDetails` might look like:

```
@Test
@WithUserDetails("usernameThatIsFoundByUserDetailsService")
public void run() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .etc;
}
```

The alternative is to use [@WithSecurityContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withsecuritycontext). This makes sense if you do not want to require the user to actually exist (as is necessary for WithUserDetails). I won't elaborate on this as it is well documented and without more details about your object model, I cannot provide a concrete example of this.

Comment: Wow, thanks @Rob. I went for the RequestPostProcessor option, which worked a treat.

Comment: Given that I'm using @PreAuthorize on my service methods, what's the best practice way to ensure my test classes can call these methods? At the moment I'm using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth)

Comment: If the methods are being invoked through MockMvc, then this answer still applies. If you are invoking the method directly, you can use the annotation approach or set the security context directly. There is documentation around this in the reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method

Comment: Re the above answer - using with user is working fine for get but not for post. Is this expected?

Comment: In that, calling mockMvc.perform(post.with(user(principal))) with post built  using MockMvcRequestBuilders.post, gives a 403.

Comment: Maybe because they redirect?

Comment: Likely the POST fails because a valid CSRF token needs to be provided in the request. With the spring-security-test support you can do this using with(csrf()) See the reference for additional details http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-csrf

Comment: Duh! Oh yeah. Thanks :-)