# Null authentication @WithUserDetails in @RespositoryRestController

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-data-rest

Similar to [Authentication token passed to ControllerAdvice is null when running through MockMvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224706/authentication-token-passed-to-controlleradvice-is-null-when-running-through-moc), my MockMvc tests for a Spring Boot 1.5.16 application with Spring Data REST and Spring Security always have a null `Authentication` parameter whether I add the context manually or with `@WithUserDetails`.

Is this a bug in Spring Security's testing code, or am I messing up somewhere?

The `@RepositoryRestController` methods look like:

```
@PostMapping("/resources/{id}/attributes")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> attributes(
    @PathVariable("id") long resourceId, 
    @RequestParam(value = "file", required = true) MultipartFile file,
    Authentication authentication ) throws IOException {

    // 2.
    Subject.setAuthentication(authentication);

    try (InputStream input = file.getInputStream()) {
        attributeHandler.read(resourceId, file.getName(), input);
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(success());
}
```

and my MockMvc tests look like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class RestControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("myAttributeManagerUsername")
    public void attributes() throws Exception {     

        // 1.
        Authentication authentication = 
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload(
                "/api/resources/1/attributes"
            ).file(attributesFile())
            // 3. .with(authentication(authentication)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Within the test method (at 1.) I have verified that authentication is present, but when the controller method is called (at 2.) the authentication is null, even if I manually set the context (at 3.) via `.sessionAttr()` or `.with()` (as shown). When running the application outside of the tests, the controller methods do get a proper authentication token (at 2.) with authenticated subjects.

Any ideas what's wrong in my tests?

Comment: As far as what you have posted here, I've replicated your posted code in a GitHub sample: https://github.com/jzheaux/so-53875541 where the test passes. Perhaps there is some additional configuration that you have not posted?

Comment: ^^^ Nice @jzheaux! Looks like you're right - I'm playing with your sample and my application to narrow down the problem (looks like it's somewhere in my user details + service implementations). I'll report next week. I owe you a beer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gee. This is not likely to be particularly helpful but...

As part of my (not shown) infrastructure, a filter incorrectly reset the authentication prior to the API which triggered this bug.

Sorry about the noise.